# How can I call a different Node.js script from my own?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-commander

I am building an application that bundles several CLI apps together using Node.js for internal use.  I'm using several NPM dependencies, and some of those have their own binaries for CLI commands.

For user friendliness, I'm using [`Commander`'s git-style sub-commands](https://github.com/tj/commander.js#git-style-sub-commands) for my own application.  The module requires there to be a separate `.js` file for each of the sub-commands that act as binaries.

This is similar to what I have so far, and what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
var program = require('commander'),
    spawn   = require('child_process').spawn;

program.parse(process.argv);

var args = ['./node_modules/exampleDep/.bin/index.js'].push(program.args);

var wrap = spawn('node', args);

wrap.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  process.stdout.write(data);
});

wrap.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  process.stderr.write(data);
});
```

So basically I'm trying to wrap another binary within my own.  This method works, but it feels somewhat hack-ish and it opens 2 instances of `Node.exe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `child_process.fork`: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options

> This is a special case of the child_process.spawn() functionality for spawning Node.js processes. In addition to having all the methods in a normal ChildProcess instance, the returned object has a communication channel built-in. See [child.send(message, [sendHandle])][] for details.

or if you don't want to spawn new NodeJS process, you can use `vm` module:
https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed that.  Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: @Eclecticist please note that I've added reference to `vm` module - very handy if you want to run multiple times not big code that you trust. Especially handy if you have use-case where you need several execution "sandboxes". However, script is run in same VM, so not in parallel.